# What's the difference between a lens and a partial lens?

Tags: scala, haskell, scalaz, lenses, calmm

A "lens" and a "partial lens" seem rather similar in name and in concept. How do they differ? In what circumstances do I need to use one or the other?

Tagging Scala and Haskell, but I'd welcome explanations related to any functional language that has a lens library.

Comment: Looks like what Scala calls a PLens is called a prism in Haskell. Turns out it's a dual concept to a lens working along sums where lenses work along products.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To describe partial lenses—which I will henceforth call, according to the Haskell `lens` nomenclature, prisms (excepting that they're not! See the comment by Ørjan)—I'd like to begin by taking a different look at lenses themselves.

A lens `Lens s a` indicates that given an `s` we can "focus" on a subcomponent of `s` at type `a`, viewing it, replacing it, and (if we use the lens family variation `Lens s t a b`) even changing its type.

One way to look at this is that `Lens s a` witnesses an isomorphism, an equivalence, between `s` and the tuple type `(r, a)` for some *unknown* type `r`.

```
Lens s a ====== exists r . s ~ (r, a)
```

This gives us what we need since we can pull the `a` out, replace it, and then run things back through the equivalence backward to get a new `s` with out updated `a`.

---

Now let's take a minute to refresh our high school algebra via algebraic data types. Two key operations in ADTs are multiplication and summation. We write the type `a * b` when we have a type consisting of items which have *both* an `a` and a `b` and we write `a + b` when we have a type consisting of items which are *either* `a` or `b`.

In Haskell we write `a * b` as `(a, b)`, the tuple type. We write `a + b` as `Either a b`, the either type.

Products represent bundling data together, sums represent bundling *options* together. Products can represent the idea of having many things only one of which you'd like to choose (at a time) whereas sums represent the idea of failure because you were hoping to take one option (on the *left* side, say) but instead had to settle for the other one (along the *right*).

Finally, sums and products are categorical duals. They *fit together* and having one without the other, as most PLs do, puts you in an awkward place.

---

So let's take a look at what happens when we *dualize* (part of) our lens formulation above.

```
exists r . s ~ (r + a)
```

This is a declaration that `s` is *either* a type `a` *or* some other thing `r`. We've got a `lens`-like thing that embodies the notion of option (and of failure) deep at it's core.

This is exactly a prism (or partial lens)

```
Prism s a ====== exists r . s ~ (r + a)
                 exists r . s ~ Either r a
```

So how does this work concerning some simple examples?

Well, consider the prism which "unconses" a list:

```
uncons :: Prism [a] (a, [a])
```

it's equivalent to this

```
head :: exists r . [a] ~ (r + (a, [a]))
```

and it's relatively obvious what `r` entails here: total failure since we have an empty list!

To substantiate the type `a ~ b` we need to write a way to transform an `a` into a `b` and a `b` into an `a` such that they invert one another. Let's write that in order to describe our prism via the mythological function

```
prism :: (s ~ exists r . Either r a) -> Prism s a

uncons = prism (iso fwd bck) where
  fwd []     = Left () -- failure!
  fwd (a:as) = Right (a, as)
  bck (Left ())       = []
  bck (Right (a, as)) = a:as
```

This demonstrates how to use this equivalence (at least in principle) to create prisms and also suggests that they ought to feel really natural whenever we're working with sum-like types such as lists.

Comment: I do not think "partial lens" and "prism" are quite the same thing. Note that the "nth element of a `List`" example @ChrisMartin's documentation paste lists isn't a prism. It's more like "traversal with at most one target", which I don't think has its own type in `lens`.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point :( those would be "affine traversals" I suppose.

Comment: And Haskell has its own notion of [partial lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-2.10.7/docs/Data-Lens-Partial-Common.html) that is distinct from prism, right?

Comment: @ChrisMartin That's a very different lens library, so not used as much I think.

Answer (score 10):

A lens is a "functional reference" that allows you to extract and/or update a generalized "field" in a larger value.  For an ordinary, non-partial lens that field is always required to be *there*, for any value of the containing type. This presents a problem if you want to look at something like a "field" which might not always be there.  For example, in the case of "the nth element of a list" (as listed in the Scalaz documentation @ChrisMartin pasted), the list might be too short.

Thus, a "partial lens" generalizes a lens to the case where a field may or may not always be present in a larger value.

There are at least three things in the Haskell [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library that you could think of as "partial lenses", none of which corresponds exactly to the Scala version:

- An ordinary [`Lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:Lens) whose "field" is a `Maybe` type.
- A [`Prism`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Prism), as described by @J.Abrahamson.
- A [`Traversal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversal).

They all have their uses, but the first two are too restricted to include all cases, while `Traversal`s are "too general". Of the three, only `Traversal`s support the "nth element of list" example.

- For the "`Lens` giving a `Maybe`-wrapped value" version, what breaks is the lens laws: to have a proper lens, you should be able to set it to `Nothing` to remove the optional field, then set it back to what it was, and then get back the same value.  This works fine for a `Map` say (and [`Control.Lens.At.at`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#g:1) gives such a lens for `Map`-like containers), but not for a list, where deleting e.g. the `0`th element cannot avoid disturbing the later ones.
- A `Prism` is in a sense a generalization of a *constructor* (approximately case class in Scala) rather than a field.  As such the "field" it gives when present should contain *all* the information to regenerate the whole structure (which you can do with the `review` function.)
- A `Traversal` can do "nth element of a list" just fine, in fact there are at least two different functions [`ix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#g:2) and [`element`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:element) that both work for this (but generalize slightly differently to other containers).

Thanks to the typeclass magic of `lens`, any `Prism` or `Lens` automatically works as a `Traversal`, while a `Lens` giving a `Maybe`-wrapped optional field can be turned into a `Traversal` of a plain optional field by composing with `traverse`.

However, a `Traversal` is in some sense *too* general, because it is not restricted to a single field: A `Traversal` can have *any* number of "target" fields. E.g.

```
elements odd
```

is a `Traversal` that will happily go through all the odd-indexed elements of a list, updating and/or extracting information from them all.

In theory, you could define a fourth variant (the "affine traversals" @J.Abrahamson mentions) that I think might correspond more closely to Scala's version, but due to a technical reason outside the `lens` library itself they would not fit well with the rest of the library - you would have to explicitly convert such a "partial lens" to use some of the `Traversal` operations with it.

Also, it would not buy you much over ordinary `Traversal`s, since there's e.g. a simple operator [`(^?)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.12.3/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) to extract just the first element traversed.

(As far as I can see, the technical reason is that the [`Pointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-4.2.0.2/docs/Data-Pointed.html) typeclass which would be needed to define an "affine traversal" is not a superclass of `Applicative`, which ordinary `Traversal`s use.)

Comment: Do you have an opinion favoring the haskell or the scalaz design? Is one of them underfeatured or less correct than the other?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Sorry, I don't really know Scala.

Answer (score 8):

#### Scalaz documentation

Below are the scaladocs for Scalaz's `LensFamily` and `PLensFamily`, with emphasis added on the diffs.

Lens:

> [***A Lens Family***](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.LensFamily), offering a purely functional means to access and retrieve ***a field*** transitioning from type `B1` to type `B2` in a record simultaneously transitioning from type `A1` to type `A2`. ***`scalaz.Lens`*** is a convenient alias for when `A1 =:= A2`, and `B1 =:= B2`.
>
> The term "field" should not be interpreted restrictively to mean a member of a class. For example, ***a lens family can address membership of a `Set`***.

Partial lens:

> [***Partial Lens Families***](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.PLensFamily), offering a purely functional means to access and retrieve ***an optional field*** transitioning from type `B1` to type `B2` in a record that is simultaneously transitioning from type `A1` to type `A2`. ***`scalaz.PLens`*** is a convenient alias for when `A1 =:= A2`, and `B1 =:= B2`.
>
> The term "field" should not be interpreted restrictively to mean a member of a class. For example, ***a partial lens family can address the nth element of a `List`***.

#### Notation

For those unfamiliar with scalaz, we should point out the symbolic type aliases:

```
type @>[A, B] = Lens[A, B]
type @?>[A, B] = PLens[A, B]
```

In infix notation, this means the type of a lens that retrieves a field of type `B` from a record of type `A` is expressed as `A @> B`, and a partial lens as `A @?> B`.

#### Argonaut

[Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/) (a JSON library) provides a lot of examples of partial lenses, because the schemaless nature of JSON means that attempting to retrieve something from an arbitrary JSON value always has the possibility of failure. Here are a few examples of lens-constructing functions from Argonaut:

- `def jArrayPL: Json @?> JsonArray` — Retrieves a value only if the JSON value is an array
- `def jStringPL: Json @?> JsonString` — Retrieves a value only if the JSON value is a string
- `def jsonObjectPL(f: JsonField): JsonObject @?> Json` — Retrieves a value only if the JSON object has the field `f`
- `def jsonArrayPL(n: Int): JsonArray @?> Json` — Retrieves a value only if the JSON array has an element at index `n`